# What has priority, Kavod or Oneg Shabbat

Tags: halacha, priorities, kavod, orach-chaim, oneg-shabbat

Does Halacha have a preference for either Oneg Shabbat or Kavod Shabbat? For example, if a fancy suit would make a Jew uncomfortable (like during summer) that would be Kavod Shabbat but hurt Oneg Shabbat, and not wearing it would be the opposite. Which one should be picked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Halachapedia addresses a similar scenario [here](https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Kavod_and_Oneg_Shabbat#cite_note-8):

> If wearing a nice tie or jacket on Shabbat in the summer makes a person very hot and uncomfortable some say that it is preferable to wear fancy respectable clothing but not be uncomfortable than to be even fancier and uncomfortable.

The footnote there reads as follows:

> Chashukei Chemed Shabbat 25b quotes the Chazon Ish as saying that if a person feels that wearing a tie on Shabbat will make him hot and uncomfortable then it isn't a fulfillment of Kavod Shabbat, honoring Shabbat, if it won't also fulfill Oneg Shabbat, enjoying Shabbat. Or Avraham Brachot siman 79 quotes this as well from the Maaseh Ish p. 134. Chut Shani Shabbat ch. 1 fnt. 2 is cited to agree with the Chazon Ish and explain that it isn't a condition in Kavod Shabbat to be Oneg Shabbat but that it isn't a violation to Kavod Shabbat to remove the uncomfortable clothing when it isn't Oneg Shabbat. [Rivevot Efraim 3:554](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1085&st=&pgnum=383&hilite=) agrees. See [Shalmei Yohanatan 242:1](https://tablet.otzar.org/#/book/152648/p/26/t/8745921881234/fs/0/start/0/end/0/c) p. 32 who poses the question whether it preferable to use challah that is store bought and nicer since it is more Kavod Shabbat or the tastier homemade bread since it is more Oneg Shabbat.